# How to run constructor even if "-nostdlib" option is defined

Tags: c, gcc, shared-libraries

I have a dynamic library that contains a constructor.

```
__attribute__ ((constructor))
void construct() {
    // This is initialization code
}
```

The library is compiled with `-nostdlib` option and I cannot change that. As a result there are no `.ctor` and `.dtor` sections in library and the constructor is not running on the library load.

As written [there](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO.html#INIT-AND-CLEANUP) there should be special measures that allow running the constructor even in this case. Could you please advice me what and how that can be done?

Comment: the page you linked says "Shared libraries must not be compiled with the gcc arguments `-nostartfiles` or `-nostdlib`. If those arguments are used, the constructor/destructor routines will not be executed (unless special measures are taken)."

Comment: Yes, I understand that. But it also mentions that there are special measures that can be taken.

Comment: if you use `-nostdlib`, you should also add `-lgcc`; however, this might not actually help with your problem; you'll probably have to use `_init()` and `_fini()` instead of constructors and destructors...

Comment: I have already linked to `libgcc.a` explicitly. I will try to find an appropriate example with `_init()` and `_fini()`.

Comment: Regardless of using -nostdlib, there should still be .ctor and .dtor sections generated by the compiler. Perhaps what you need to do is use a custom linker script to gather up all the constructors. I've done these "special measures" before, but that was for the special circumstance of making a ROM boot loader. I think you're asking for a world of unmaintainable pain if you're doing this for something intended to be runtime shared.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need constructors? Most programmers I work with, myself included, refuse to use libraries with global constructors because all too often they introduce bugs by messing up the program's initial state when `main` is entered. One concrete example I can think of is `OpenAL`, which broke programs when it was merely linked, even if it was never called. I was not the one on the project who dealt with this bug, but if I'm not mistaken it had something to do with mucking with ALSA and breaking the main program's use of ALSA later.

If your library has nontrivial global state, instead see if you can simply use global structs and initializers. You might need to add flags with some pointers to indicate whether they point to allocated memory or static memory, though. Another method is to defer initialization to the first call, but this can have thread-safety issues unless you use `pthread_once` or similar.

Comment: This is a special case. I have almost all code in binary encrypted. And only constructor is not encrypted.

Comment: OK, I'm finished helping with this question then. You're obviously trying to make things hell for people using your library code so you can do that on your own.

Answer (score 0):

On some platforms, `.init_array/.fini_array` sections are generated to include all global constructors/destructors. You may use that.

Comment: This is mostly for embedded platforms, on x86 platforms they are called .ctor and .dtor :)

Comment: From gcc 4.6.2, init_array/init_array is the default section for holding global constructors and destructors. More details at http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46770

Answer (score 0):

Hmm missed the part that there where no .ctor and .dtor sections... forget about this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef void (*func)(void);

__attribute__((constructor))
void func1(void) {
     printf("func1\n");
}

__attribute__((constructor))
void func2(void) {
     printf("func2\n");
}

extern func* __init_array_start;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
     func *funcarr = (func*)&__init_array_start;
     func f;
     int idx;

     printf("start %p\n", *funcarr);

     // iterate over the array
     for (idx = 0; ; ++idx) {
          f = funcarr[idx];

          // skip the end of array marker (0xFFFFFFFF) on 64 bit it's twice as long ;)
          if (f == (void*)~0)
               continue;

          // till f is NULL which indicates the start of the array
          if (f == NULL)
               break;

          printf("constructor %p\n", *f);
          f();
     }

     return 0;
}
```

Which gives:

```
Compilation started at Fri Mar  9 09:28:29

make test && ./test
 cc     test.c   -o test
 func2
 func1
 start 0xffffffff
 constructor 0x80483f4
 func1
 constructor 0x8048408
 func2
```

Probably you need to swap the continue and break if you are running on an Big Endian system but i'm not entirely sure.

But just like R.. stated using static constructors in libraries is not so nice to the developers using your library :p